# PHP - doesn't recognize and display an input

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

PHP noob here, I'm stuck at a point in my personal project. I want to show a second rate (rental website) for an item but I've failed to get the second price to show. I'll paste the code and a snapshot. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxje.png)

So basically, I'd like the user to input two rates for an item and display both on the item details page. So the the problem is that the second rate isn't registering.

The code is divided into a `create.blade.php` (where the user makes input) and `details.blade.php` (responsible for the resulting picture).

```
<!-- CREATE.BLADE.PHP CODE HERE -->
<!-- customFields -->
            <div id="customFields"></div>

                <!-- price -->
        <?php $priceError = (isset($errors) and $errors->has('price')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>
              <div id="priceBloc" class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="price">{{ t('Price') }}</label>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">{!! config('currency')['symbol'] !!}</span>
                    </div>

                        <input id="price"
                               name="price"
                               class="form-control{{ $priceError }}"
                               placeholder="{{ t('e.i. 15000') }}"
                               type="text" value="{{ old('price') }}"
                        >


    <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <input id="negotiable" name="negotiable" type="checkbox"
                                    value="1" {{ (old('negotiable')=='1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>&nbsp;<small>{{ t('Negotiable') }}</small>
                            </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Price 2-->
                                        <?php $priceError = (isset($errors) and $errors->has('price2')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>
                                        <div id="priceBloc" class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="price2">Rate per Week</label>
                                            <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text">{!! config('currency')['symbol'] !!}</span>
                                            </div>

                                                <input id="price2"
                                                       name="price2"
                                                       class="form-control{{ $priceError }}"
                                                       placeholder="{{ t('e.i. 15000') }}"
                                                       type="text" value="{{ old('price2') }}"
                                                >

                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                                        <input id="negotiable" name="negotiable" type="checkbox"
                                                               value="1" {{ (old('negotiable')=='1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>&nbsp;<small>{{ t('Negotiable') }}</small>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
<!-- END -->
```

Contents of `details.blade.php`:

```
<!--DETAILS.BLADE.PHP CODE HERE -->

    @if (!in_array($post->category->type, ['not-salable']))
                            <!-- Price / Salary -->
                <div class="detail-line-lite col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div>
                        <span>
                    {{ (!in_array($post->category->type, ['job-offer', 'job-search'])) ? t('Price') : t('Salary') }}:
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            @if ($post->price > 0)
                                {!! \App\Helpers\Number::money($post->price) !!}
                              @else
                                {!! \App\Helpers\Number::money(' --') !!}
                            @endif
                            @if ($post->negotiable == 1)
                                <small class="label badge-success"> {{ t('Negotiable') }}</small>
                            @endif
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <!-- Price 2 / Salary -->
                <div class="detail-line-lite col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div>
                        <span>
{{ (!in_array($post->category->type, ['job-offer', 'job-search'])) ? t('Price per week') : t('Salary') }}:


    </span>
                        <span>
                            @if ($post->price2 > 0)
                              {!! \App\Helpers\Number::money($post->price2) !!}
                            @else
                              {!! \App\Helpers\Number::money(' --') !!}
                            @endif
                            @if ($post->negotiable == 1)
                                <small class="label badge-success"> {{ t('Negotiable') }}</small>
                            @endif
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
   <!-- END-->
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP :)

Comment: Your `details.blade.php` is trying to get `$post->priceperweek` but there is no such input field. The only input fields I see are named `price` and `price2`. It looks like you're confusing the `id` with the `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks I'll correct that

Comment: I did the correction as suggested but the result is still the same

Comment: Please indicate the line(s) in `details.blade.php` which are not working.